# Why does MariaDBb allow insert of text into smallint

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mariadb

My server provider has replaced MYSQL with MariaDB which seems to be working differently.  The information on this server I get when I run “SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';”  is:

Variable_name Value 
   protocol_version   10
   slave_type_conversions 
  version 5.5.58-MariaDB 
  version_comment MariaDB Server 
  version_compile_machine x86_64 
  version_compile_os   Linux

The SQL statement “INSERT INTO years (`Year`) VALUES ('test');” inserts a 0 into a smallint field using either Aria or MyISAM engine

On my local development system when I run “SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';”  I get:

Variable_name   Value 
  innodb_version  5.6.21 
  protocol_version    10 
  slave_type_conversions  
  version 5.6.21-log 
  version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
  version_compile_machine x86_64 
  version_compile_os  Win64

The same SQL statement “INSERT INTO years (`Year`) VALUES ('test');” using a MYISAM engine produces Error Code: 1366 “Incorrect integer value ‘test’ for column ‘Year’ at row 1” which is what I expecting and was relying on.

Can anyone shed any light onto why this is like this?

Comment: because of two things first one being the https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/type-conversion/ and a configuration: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me put it in a proper answer. This happens because of two things, one being the [Type conversion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/type-conversion/) And the main reason is the STRICT_MODE configuration which is in the [SQL Modes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/) Configuration section.

The **Strict Mode** states

> A mode where at least one of STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or STRICT_ALL_TABLES is enabled is called strict mode. With strict mode not set (default in version <= MariaDB 10.2.3), MariaDB will automatically adjust invalid values, for example, truncating strings that are too long, or adjusting numeric values that are out of range, and produce a warning.
>
> With strict mode set (default from MariaDB 10.2.4), the statements will fail, and an error will be returned instead. The IGNORE keyword can be used when strict mode is set to convert the error to a warning.

Comment: I'm using a for a PHP MySQLi DB class and so putting  $db->rawQuery("SET sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'"); before my INSERT solved this.    Thanks